# Is there a way to override the minumum font size in webkit browsers?

Tags: javascript, canvas, fonts, webkit, font-size

I am rendering tiny text on a canvas instance and it works as expected on Firefox 4, but on Chrome and Safari the font renders using the minimum font size set in these browsers, which is already at its minimum and can't be lowered through the UI, (which looks like a 6px font size) but it is still too big for what I want to accomplish.

The code I am using to print the font is similar to the following, in case it might be useful:

```
ctx.font = '4px Monospace';
ctx.fillText("Any text", 0, 10);
```

So, is it possible at all to override the minimum font size settings?

**Update**: I know a text is not readable at 4px, but that's not the point of the question. I don't need it to be readable at all, as a matter of fact.

**Update 2**: On Safari [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295095/font-size-12px-doesnt-have-effect-in-google-chrome/4316700#4316700) works, but it still doesn't work in Chrome.

Thanks.

Comment: 4px? noone uses such small font...

Comment: the idea is that if you have a text that is visible it should be readable by user

Comment: A 4px is hardly going to be readable on any machine

Comment: It works perfectly for me...
http://jsfiddle.net/YSU8H/7/

Comment: @OmerPT: this is significantly bigger than 2px for me (Chromium on Ubuntu).

Comment: How about this? http://jsfiddle.net/YSU8H/9/
I added a style to the canvas, maybe it will sort it out, it should sort it out on regular elements

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295095/font-size-12px-doesnt-have-effect-in-google-chrome has a few solutions

Comment: @OmerPT: It doesn't work. Change the font size to 1, 3 or 4 for example. It looks the same.

Comment: Doesn't look the same for me, maybe your chromium is buggy... try getting regular Chrome...


And @James, we're talking about canvas text not regular text

Comment: @OmerPT I am using regular Chrome 12.0.742

Answer (score 2):

You could try using a bigger font and [scaling the context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial/Transformations#Scaling):

```
ctx.font = '8px Monospace';
ctx.save();
ctx.scale(0.5, 0.5);
ctx.fillText("Any text", 0, 20);
ctx.restore();
```

Remember to keep the scaling in mind when specifying the position of your text.

This could easily reduce the graphics quality of the text, but at that size it will be pretty unreadable anyway.

Comment: That's a good idea, I will try it. I am wary of performance problems though, because I am drawing text on a loop that can easily run thousands of iterations.