# Is it possible to use css font-size smaller than 8px on Android version 2 or lower

Tags: android, css, browser, font-size

I need to use font-size smaller than 8px. But Android version 2 or earlier seems to force font-size to 8px as the smallest size.

Is there any way to get the font-size smaller than 8px?

Here is the html/css I use:

```
...
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
...

<p style="font-size: 12px">Hello 12px</p>
<p style="font-size: 11px">Hello 11px</p>
<p style="font-size: 10px">Hello 10px</p>
<p style="font-size: 9px">Hello 9px</p>
<p style="font-size: 8px">Hello 8px</p>
<p style="font-size: 7px">Hello 7px</p>
<p style="font-size: 6px">Hello 6px</p>
<p style="font-size: 5px">Hello 5px</p>
<p style="font-size: 4px">Hello 4px</p>
<p style="font-size: 3px">Hello 3px</p>
<p style="font-size: 2px">Hello 2px</p>
```

And here is the result on an Andorid 2.2:

[image: Android 2.2]

Comment: it may be possible with skyfire and not with the built in browser that comes with that version the android os.  Check another droid browser.

Comment: I'm sorry that's not an option. I need it to work on the default browser...

Answer (score -3, accepted):

And the answer is yes, use this line in you css:

```
-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
```

[Answer found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4316700/141338)

[And you may read this as well](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201011/beware_of_-webkit-text-size-adjustnone/)

Comment: This doesn't work for font-size: 0. In this case, if the point is remove undesired spaces between inline-block elements, a solution is something like letter-spacing: -10px (-1 seems not to work in all cases).