# font-size less than 12px cannot work in the new version chrome browser of windows OS

Tags: css, google-chrome, font-size

Chrome removed its private CSS property `-webkit-text-size-adjust:none/auto` in the new version of windows OS. The chrome default setting about font-size is 12px. If less than 12px,it cannot work. Many articles said that setting `-webkit-transform:scale(number)` can be worked,but it will affect Safari. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you show some code which quickly shows the problem?

Comment: .smallsize{-webkit-text-size-ajust:none;font-size:9px;}

Comment: please insure your chrome is the newest

Comment: Works fine for me in Chrome `27.0.1453.116m`. Maybe you could set up a jsfiddle to show your problem? There might be other attributes which affect each other.

Comment: My Chrome version is 27.0.1453.116m too.The difference may be I use Chinese version.This version's default setting of font-size is 12px.I don't know how to change it by css or js.I set "-webkit-text-size-adjust:none" to disable Chrome's setting before.But it didn't work any more after updating  in WINDOWS OS.

Comment: @w4rumy ,do you sure the English version works fine if less than 12px?Of course without resetting default setting by hand.

Comment: Please set up a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to demonstrate your problem. This way we can be sure that we are using exact the same code.

Comment: @w4rumy here is the jsfiddle.[link](http://jsfiddle.net/r569594043/eQrd4/)

Comment: Looks fine for me, so unfortunately there is not much I can help. Maybe try to test on different PCs... In guess that something else may cause the issue... But withoug being able to reproduce it, I can't say.

Comment: I looked up some technical documentation,it shows that Chrome removed the "-webkit-text-size-adjust" in windows OS both Chinese and English version.After trying,I found that only Chinese version has this "12px" problem.English version default setting of font-size is tiny.

If users don't change this default setting by hand,the problem will be solved.

But is not a solution.
@w4rumy ,Thank you very much!

Comment: hey guys, 怎么解决的？我也遇到这个问题了，最新版的chrome不好用了啊

Comment: Refer this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295095/font-size-12px-doesnt-have-effect-in-google-chrome

Comment: refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22204108/5708287

just change some chrome configuration