# How to override computed style of Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, web-applications, fonts

I am developing a webapp using sencha framework supported in various countries.If I set the Google chrome language as "China", the app doesn't render properly. The whole CSS styling is gone for a toss. I cannot rewrite the whole style just for a specific language (China)... After a lot of debugging I found that the Google Chrome always set a minimum font size of 12px for Chinese. This is causing the issue and hence my styles are broken. I need the font-size to be set as "2.94"px. How can I override this 12px which the Chrome is calculating ? In other languages, the Chrome sets the font-size as "2.94" itself. Only China and Korean language has this different font size computed by Chrome... Please help on this issue.

Comment: font-size: 12px;
Style Attribute - 2.87px
This is what I see in computed style of Chrome...I want to get rid of this 12px computed by Chrome only for Chinese language

Comment: Please take a look here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295095/font-size-12px-doesnt-have-effect-in-google-chrome]

Comment: I tried this....But it didn't work...
body{
         -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
        },

Looks like the -webkit-text-size-adjust is deprecated...

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the old fix to use
the css-reset technique by using

> *{
>   -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
>   }

is not working anymore.

An alternative is described here: https://www.fyianlai.com/2012/01/google-chrome-minimum-font-size-issue/

using the chrome preferences to set a different minimum font size.