# Can't change PrimeFaces message styling

Tags: css, primefaces

So I am trying to change the styling on the error messages that i get through the  element, but for some reason the css isn't applied.

This is an example of a message I'm trying to change:

```
<p:inputText type="text" class="form-control" id="emailInput" value="#{signupBackingBean.email}" required="true" requiredMessage="This field is required" ></p:inputText>
<p:message for="emailInput" id="emailError" display="text" styleClass="message"></p:message>
```

and this is the CSS Im trying to apply:

```
.ui-message-info, .ui-message-error, .ui-message-warn, .ui-message-fatal {
font-size: 5px;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For the ones just upvoting the previous comment, use the 'close' link to actually vote to close it as duplicate instead of just upvoting the comment

Comment: Your CSS rule should be more specific than the ones PF is using

Comment: It absolutely works I do this in all my apps. See the docs: https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/8_0/#/components/message?id=skinning

Comment: By the way, browsers might have a minimum font size (5px is very small). There are several issues about that, for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295095/font-size-12px-doesnt-have-effect-in-google-chrome/2295108

Comment: Thanks for the help!